# Return file with only urls that keywords were found

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to use scrapy to scrape through a list of urls and get as an output only the urls that a specific keyword was found. I have tried the if statement through shell and it seems to be working --I tried if(..): exit() and it did exit the shell-- but the output of the following is an empty file (using the same url that returned the if statement as true in shell).

```
def parse(self, response):

    filename = f'file.txt'
    
    if (response.css('*').re('keyword')):
            with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.url)
            self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You open file in write-binary mode and try to write strings to it, this should raise an error.

Instead open file in append mode: `with open(filename, 'a') as f:`

Or just in write mode: `with open(filename, 'a') as f:`